# TYPO3 v10 Persistence mapping

Tags: class, typo3, mapping, persistence, typo3-10.x

TYPO3 v10 has changed the way that maps the persistence classes. The old way looks like this:

```
config.tx_extension_extension {
   persistence {
     classes {
        Vendor\ExtensionExtend\Domain\Model\Object{
           mapping {
             tableName = tx_extension_domain_model_object
           }
        }
        Vendor\ExtensionExtend\Domain\Model\Object1{
           mapping {
             tableName = tx_extension_domain_model_object1
           }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

How is this possible on TYPO3 v10?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you should do the following:

**1. Step**

Create the ***Classes.php*** file under your **extension_extend/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/**

**2. Step**

Return something like that:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

return [
    \Vendor\ExtensionExtend\Domain\Model\Object::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_extension_domain_model_object',
    ],
    \Vendor\ExtensionExtend\Domain\Model\Object1::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_extension_domain_model_object1',
    ],
];
```

And you 're ready to go.

**Documentation**

[Breaking: #87623 - Replace config.persistence.classes typoscript configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87623-ReplaceConfigpersistenceclassesTyposcriptConfiguration.html)

Best regards