# TYPO3 10.4 new fields not found in frontend

Tags: typo3-10.x

I have extended database table `fe_users` with new field using extension builder. The fields are visible in backend user-interface, but not available in frontend in Typo3 10.4.x . But the same code works fine in Typo3 9.x frontend and backend.

I have also tried setting recordType to nothing in the `ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript` but this also does not help

```
mapping {
    tableName = fe_users
    recordType = 
}
```

Any ideas on what more to look for?

Comment: What Michael wrote is absolutely right. Take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616920/typo3-v10-persistence-mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table mapping of the Extbase persistence is not longer possible in TypoScript. Migrate your TypoScript to a PHP file named `EXT:myextension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php`.

See [breaking change 87623](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87623-ReplaceConfigpersistenceclassesTyposcriptConfiguration.html) for further details.

A typical `Classes.php` file looks like the following.

```php
<?php

return [
  \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\Object::class => [
    'tableName' => 'tx_extension_domain_model_object',
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it. There was one more line (.i.e 'subclasses') that had to be added to Michael's response. (This is tested in Typo3 11.x as well)

My Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

return [
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser::class => [
      'subclasses' => [
          '\T3IN\T3inStores\Domain\Model\UserStore' => \T3IN\T3inStores\Domain\Model\UserStore::class,
      ]        
    ], 
    \T3IN\T3inStores\Domain\Model\UserStore::class => [
        'tableName' => 'fe_users',
        'recordType' => 'Tx_T3inStores_UserStore',
    ],
];
```

[Ref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/5-modeling-the-class-hierarchy.html)

- For every superclass additional all subclasses have to be declared under subclasses
- recordType : Look up the TCA of the model to get this value. Or lookup DB after creating a record of that type.