# Typo3 v10 Persistence Mapping foreignClass

Tags: mapping, typo3, persistence, extbase

since Typo3 v10 you have to use Classes.php file in Configuration/extbase/Persistence Folder for configuration of persistence table mapping.

Does anyone know how to implement

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {

    Domain\DomainUsergroupMailer\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroups { 
    mapping {
        tableName = fe_groups
        columns {
            subgroup.foreignClass = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup
        }
    } 
}
```

I can't find documentation concerning the foreignClass Parameter.
I found parameter subclasses in https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/6-Persistence/5-modeling-the-class-hierarchy.html

Does anyone know if this is the right way parameter and how to use it?

Thank you

Comment: what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616920/typo3-v10-persistence-mapping/60616921#60616921

Comment: This is the current description about the Classes:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html
An example for subclasses can be found in the extension news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There never was such a feature in TYPO3 as confirmed by searching the TYPO3v9 source code for `foreignClass`. So this must be provided by a 3rd party extension.

However, from the name it sounds like you only need to use an appropriate element type for your collection relation:

```php
/**
 * @var ObjectStorage<FrontendUserGroup>
 */
private ObjectStorage $subgroup;
```

See [Implementing the domain model](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html) for details.

Comment: It was there, but that is 12 years ago. I found that in a commit before release of TYPO3 4.3: https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/commit/24e34dbeef45adac26a54bc66afdcd707b697349

Comment: makes sense, it's an old extension, indeed.
So I think I just don't migrate that piece of code.

Comment: If it was useful, you can accept my answer. :-)

Comment: sorry for the delay, of course I will accept your answer