# TYPO3 V11 : "PHP Warning: Undefined array key" , $this->request->getArguments() is empty

Tags: php, typo3

I'm a new user of typo3 and I made a plugin to display users with a searchbar to filter them, but I have this error when I want to display my page :

```
(1/1) #1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception
PHP Warning: Undefined array key "word" in MyPath/Controller/UserlistController.php line 44
```

In my controller, I try to get arguments to use it in my filter like this :

```
   public function listAction(int $currentPage = 1)
{
   $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
   $users = $this->userlistRepository->findBySearch($arguments['word'] ? $arguments['word'] : '');

somecode ...

}
```

I tried a dump of $arguments, but it's empty

there is a part of my repository :

```
/**
     * @param string $word
     * @return object[]|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface
     * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Exception\InvalidQueryException
     */
    public function findBySearch(string $word) {
        $query = $this->persistenceManager->createQueryForType(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser::class);
        $querySettings = $query->getQuerySettings();
        $querySettings->setStoragePageIds([26]);
        $query->setQuerySettings($querySettings);

        $query->setOrderings([
            'lastName' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
        ]);
```

Someone know why I can't get arguments ? thanks

If you need more part of code, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

If you just call the List action without sending the filter form the arguments are empty.

You should test each expected argument before accessing it like this:

```
if($this->request->hasArgument('word')) {
        $searchOption = $this->request->getArgument('word'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [null coalescencing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) here:

```
$users = $this->userlistRepository->findBySearch($arguments['word'] ?? '');
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you check if the value is set before (see the [answer of Tobias Gaertner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72964346/19540954)). Also keep in mind that

```
$this->request->getArguments();
```

only gets the arguments in your current plugin context, so any parameters looking like tx_yourplugin_p1[argument]. You have to make sure you properly pass this parameter. If you have to use the general GET parameters, you can use

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET();
```

Answer (score 0):

While the handling of the 'word' variable is one issue, I consider that if no search word is sent, perhaps another Repository-Method should be called.
Below I entered `$this->userlistRepository->findAll()` but it could also show  something else, perhaps just a template that states that a choice is required.

```
public function listAction(int $currentPage = 1)
{
   $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
   if($this->request->hasArgument('word')) {
       $searchOption = $this->request->getArgument('word');
       $users = $this->userlistRepository->findBySearch($searchOption);
   }
   else {
      $users = $this->userlistRepository->findAll();
      somecode ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions, it turns out the error is coming from my repository, I tried a simple

```
$users = $this->userlistRepository->findAll();
```

and I got this error:

> HP Warning: Undefined array key "tx_vendor_domain_model_vendor" in /mypath/htdocs/public/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapFactory.php line 224

Comment: That must be the tablename, so it's quite strange but could be configured. It seems you extended the fe_users table for the vendors, which has to be mapped.

Comment: Mapping of foreign tables is explained here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html and here is directly in the question an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197128/typo3-v10-persistence-mapping-foreignclass

Comment: If you have problems with it, you should open a new question as it's unrelated to the question on this page.